# Read json from argument instead of stdin using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Say I have JSON like so:

```
export connection_info = ` echo '{
  "values": [
    {"host":"xxx", "port": 3939},
    {"host":"yyy", "port": 7373}
  ]
}'  | jq -c `
```

And I want to read it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$connection_info" | jq -r '.values[]' |

  while read item; do

     timeout 10 telnet `jq -r "$item"` 9200 || {
        echo "Could not connect to host: $host port: $port"
     }
  done;
```

how can parse the host and port from the item? Something like this:

I could probably do:

```
host=`echo "$item" | jq -r '.host'`
port=`echo "$item" | jq -r '.port'`

timeout 10 telnet "$host" "$port" 9200
```

but is there a way to do it without using stdin?

Comment: `export connection_info = echo` will generally fail with something like `bash: export: '=': not a valid identifier`, since it is trying to export the variable with the invalid name `=`

Comment: `jq` can read from a file, and since you're using bash, you could do `jq -r .[].host < <( echo '[{"host":"xxx", "port":3939},{"host":"yyy","port":7373'}])`, but I strongly suspect there's a better way to accomplish what you want.  But it's difficult to see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I update the OP make it a little clearer - just trying to read properties from the json without having to echo to jq's stdin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Also, there's no need to export `connection_info`.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

connection_info='{
  "values": [
    {"host":"xxx", "port": 3939},
    {"host":"yyy", "port": 7373}
  ]
}'

jq -n --argjson ci "$connection_info" -cr '$ci | .values[] | "\(.host) \(.port)"' |
while read -r host port ; do
     timeout 10 telnet "$host" "$port" ||
        echo "Could not connect to host: $host port: $port"
done;
```

### Using stdin

For reference, your script could also be tweaked as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

connection_info='{
  "values": [
    {"host":"xxx", "port": 3939},
    {"host":"yyy", "port": 7373}
  ]
}'

echo "$connection_info" | jq -cr '.values[] | "\(.host) \(.port)"' |
while read -r host port ; do
     timeout 10 telnet "$host" "$port" ||
        echo "Could not connect to host: $host port: $port"
done;
```

Comment: Looks like line continuation characters were not displayed by the forum. Maybe doubling them would help.

Comment: @ColeTierney - Using bash, no line continuation characters are needed here.

Comment: @peak That's what originally got my attention. I was looking forward to leaving them out, so I tried on bash 5.0 and got an error without the line continuation characters.

Comment: I've checked using  `GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release` without incident.